# Develop an Azure Service Fabric Application with Visual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-mac

my team is creating an Azure Service Fabric application using ASP.NET/Dotnet Core. Whenever I try to import the project into my Visual Studio 2017 for Mac I get the error

> Error while trying to load the project '.../Project.sfproj: Unknown solution item type'

The solution contains several projects, some with a csproj (which I can open just fine), and some with a sfproj, that cause the problems. I can't even browse them in VS2017:[image: Failed to load]

I can run msbuild from the shell (get some Compiler errors, but that's fine), but cannot manage to load the project into my IDE. I guess I'm missing the Service Fabric SDK, but that is not available for mac afaik. I managed to pull some jars from the vagrant image, as described [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/livedevopsinjapan/2017/02/24/building-your-service-fabric-environment-on-your-mac-with-eclipse/) but that doesn't help me in a ASP.NET/Dotnet Core application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is currently not available. If anyone wants it, [vote](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17139239-service-fabric-support?utm_source=t.co&utm_medium=referral) for it on the visual studio user voice page.